# How do i update a graph automatically in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, auto

ok guys , im kinda frustrated , i've searched everywhere and everytime i try something i find in the internet i get so many error and problems and i think its time to ask how do i do that ?
i want that when i press my button , the graph that is in my GUI will update and show the new value i just added , thats my code : i've tried to mess around with figure.canvas.draw() and it is basically doing nothing , whats wrong with my code ? :

```
window = tk.Tk()

window.title("MY Weight")
frame = tk.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

#entry data
def enter_data():
    phase = phase_combobox.get()
    date1 = weight_date.get()
    weight = currently_weight_entry.get()
    
    filepath = "C:/Users/shaha/OneDrive/Desktop/Projects/weight.xlsx"
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
    sheet = workbook.active
    sheet.append([phase,date1,int(weight)])
    workbook.save(filepath)
    figure.clear()
    figure.canvas.draw()
    figure.show()

    
    
#Saving weight info
info_weight= tk.LabelFrame(frame,text="Weight Information")
info_weight.grid(row=0,column=0)


phase_label = tk.Label(info_weight,text="Currently Phase")
phase_label.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)


phase_combobox = ttk.Combobox(info_weight,values=['Bulk',"Cut",'Maintain'])
phase_combobox.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)


weight_date_label = tk.Label(info_weight,text="Date of weighing")
weight_date_label.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

sel=tk.StringVar()#So we can get the info from the calendar
weight_date = DateEntry(info_weight,selectmode='day',date_pattern='d/m/Y',textvariable=sel,locale='en_US')
weight_date.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

currently_weight = tk.Label(info_weight,text="Weight")
currently_weight.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

currently_weight_entry = tk.Entry(info_weight) 
currently_weight_entry.grid(row=5,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

#Button
button = tk.Button(info_weight,text='ENTER',command=enter_data)
button.grid(row=6,column=0,sticky='news',padx=10,pady=10)



#Graph info

info_graph = tk.LabelFrame(frame)
info_graph.grid(row=0,column=1)

figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(10,5),dpi=130)
figure_plot=figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
figure_plot.set_ylabel("Weight/Calories")
line_graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure,info_graph)
line_graph.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill=tk.BOTH)
weight.plot(x='date',y='weight',kind='line',legend=True ,ax=figure_plot,color="purple",fontsize=6)
figure_plot.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=4))
date_format = mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y')
figure_plot.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)
figure.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)


window.mainloop()
```

thanks !

tried messing around with the figure itself , nothing worked.

Comment: See [ask]. Also post a [mre] and debugging details. Anyway, see [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). You are not plotting in the ```enter_data()```.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redraw the graph each time you add a value.

Here is a solution that is using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) instead of [OpenPyXL](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import pathlib
import datetime

import tkcalendar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import pandas as pd

filepath = pathlib.Path("C:/Users/shaha/OneDrive/Desktop/Projects/weight.xlsx")

if filepath.exists():
    records = pd.read_excel(filepath, index_col=0)
else:
    records = pd.DataFrame(columns=['weight', 'phase'], index=pd.DatetimeIndex([]))

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("MY Weight")
window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame = tk.Frame(window)

def data_entered():
    new_date = datetime.datetime.combine(weight_date.get_date(), datetime.time())
    new_weight = weight_value.get()
    new_phase = phase_choices.get()

    records.loc[new_date] = {
        'weight': new_weight,
        'phase': new_phase
    }

    refresh_graph()

def refresh_graph():
    ax.clear()
    if not records['weight'].empty:
        records['weight'].plot(ax=ax, xlabel='Date', ylabel='Weight')

    canvas.draw_idle()

def save_to_file():
    records.to_excel(filepath, index_label="date", merge_cells=False)

background = ttk.Frame(window, padding=10)
background.grid(column=0, row=0,sticky=(tk.N, tk.W, tk.E, tk.S))
background.columnconfigure(0, pad=10)
background.columnconfigure(1, weight=1, pad=10)
background.rowconfigure(0, weight=0, pad=10)
background.rowconfigure(1, weight=1, pad=10)

main_group = ttk.Labelframe(background, text="Weight Information")
main_group.grid(column=0, row=0, ipadx=10, ipady=10, sticky=(tk.N, tk.W))
main_group.columnconfigure(0, weight=0, pad=10)
main_group.columnconfigure(1, weight=0, pad=10)
main_group.rowconfigure(0, pad=10)
main_group.rowconfigure(1, pad=10)
main_group.rowconfigure(2, pad=10)

phase_label = ttk.Label(main_group, text="Currently Phase")
phase_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

phase_choices = ttk.Combobox(main_group, values=['Bulk',"Cut",'Maintain'])
phase_choices.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.E)

date_label = ttk.Label(main_group, text="Date of weighing")
date_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

weight_date = tkcalendar.DateEntry(main_group, selectmode="day", date_pattern="d/m/Y", locale='en_US')
weight_date.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.E)

weight_label = ttk.Label(main_group, text="Weight")
weight_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

weight_value = tk.IntVar()
weight = ttk.Entry(main_group, textvariable=weight_value )
weight.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.E)

add_button = ttk.Button(main_group, text="Add weight value", command=data_entered)
add_button.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E))

save_button = ttk.Button(background, text="Save all data to file", command=save_to_file)
save_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=(tk.N, tk.E))

graph_backplate = ttk.Frame(background,padding=10)
graph_backplate.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=(tk.N, tk.E, tk.S, tk.W))
graph_backplate.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, pad=10)
graph_backplate.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, pad=10)

fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=graph_backplate)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.E, tk.S, tk.W))

refresh_graph()

window.mainloop()
```

- Using Pandas simplifies reading and writing the Excel file and plotting the weight data as well.
- I also separated adding data and save that data to disk in two different buttons.
- You should see that we refresh the drawing of the plot in `refresh_graph()`. It is called each time new data is added.
- I have also used the [Grid geometry manager](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html) to layout the widget instead of the Pack mananger. The interface should adjust itself if resized. The layout is also a bit different from yours.

But even this code I am providing you is problematic because it relies on global variables which can create problem down the line when you want to extend your software. But I did not want to make it so different from you code that you do not recognize it.

There is not a lot a documentation on Tk so I refer you to the website [TkDocs](https://tkdocs.com/) which has more recent documentation about it. I also based this solution on the page on Matlplotlib's website that explains [how to embed a plot in a Tk interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html).